# Custom JDBC Authorisation using Spring Security 4

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-security, spring-jdbc

This is continuing after this question: [Custom LDAP authentication using Spring Security 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28554949/custom-ldap-authentication-using-spring-security). After the user has been authenticated, I need to authorize it. My roles has and the user mapping is stored in a database. I need to fetch the roles and save them in the `GrantedAuthority` object. How do I do this using Spring Security 4? I am using Java based config.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own AuthenticationProvider (i.e. a class implementing org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider) and configure Spring Security to use it. Give a look to this: Implement custom AuthenticationProvider in Spring Security 2.06