# Spring Security loadUserByUsername - create new user when username is not fuond

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

I'm building a publicly accessible training site in tandem with a bootcamp type training course.  I'd like to avoid the overhead of signing users up and managing permissions, so I was hoping to simply create a new user when loadUserByUsername is called and a user isn't found.  After researching it seems like the password isn't available to loadUserByUsername, since Spring Security handles the actual authentication on it's own, it just wants a UserDetails object returned.

So, my primary question: is there any way to pull in the password into the loadUserByUsername function?

Secondarily, if I cannot gain access to the password, can I somehow implement my User Repository and include logic there to create a new user if an existing user isn't found?

Alternatively, I have determined I could simply provide an automated sign up process, but as mentioned above, I'd love to just have the ability for a user to login for the first time creating their user account automatically in one action.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution it to create your own [AuthenticationProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html). You can start by extending [DaoAuthenticationProvider](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.html). The key is to override the authenticate method where you have access to username and password (In the Authentication). If you go with the DaoAuthenticationProvider override retrieveUser.

To do so you'll probably need to write your own UserDetailsService.

You can take a look at this [tutorial on how to write a cutom auth provider](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-limit-login-attempts-example/). Or [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8650683/1976843) or

Comment: Thanks!  I've been trying to work through the links you provided and am not getting far...  With my time constraints I don't know if I'll be able to implement a custom auth provider so I'll probably fall back to a sign up process.  Appreciate your response!